# Expected value of the sum of two jointly distributed variables?

Tags: probability

In a model for hospital room charges X and hospital surgical charges Y for a particular
type of hospital admission, the region of probability (after scaling units) is $0 ≤ y ≤ 2x + 1 ≤ 3$.

The joint density function of $X$ and $Y$ is $f(x, y) = .3(x + y)$. Find the expected excess of surgical charges over room charges for an admission (i.e $E[Y-X]$).

Correct me if I'm wrong... but this is just $$\int_0^1{\int_0^{2x+1}}{(y-x)f(x,y)dydx}$$

correct?

Comment: Looks right to me (assuming you also have the condition $x>0,$ which seems reasonable and leads to the normalization factor $3/10$ you wrote down)